# EF Applies All Migrations, Not Just New One

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 6 and when I run `Update-Database` it is trying to apply every migration since the beginning of the project, even though there is only migration that is new.

If I attempt to create an empty migration, I get an error that says I can't create a new migration because there are explicit migrations pending.

The only blog post I found with a similar issue suggested dropping the `__MigrationHistory` table and doing `Update-Database -Script`, stripping out all the actual DB changes but leaving in the `Create __MigrationHistory` and `Migration Inserts`.  I didn't drop the table, but I did rename it, and this didn't solve the problem for me.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36458229/403404) looks like a duplicate, but when I run the script I see that my context key has not changed, so that's not my problem.

What's weird is I added a column to my model, and then did an `add-migration` with no problem.  Then I went to lunch (but without doing an `update-database`), then after lunch I decided to add another column to my model and when I did `add-migration -force` again this error started.  I've completely rolled back my workspace (completely delete the workspace and removed all code from my machine), but the problem persists.

I am in a team environment, but we each use our own dev databases, and I've verified the connection string is correct in my Migrations App.Config file.

I ran SQL Profiler during the `Update-Database -Script` command, and it ran the following query 24 times before giving up (12 batches of 2) :

```
IF db_id(N'ISEPDBContexts.AdministratorDb') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'ISEPDBContexts.AdministratorDb'
```

Which is weird because that's the name of my connection string, not the name of the database.

Comment: If it's just DEV, then run the update-database -Script. Now strip out all the code except for the inserts into __MigrationHistory.  and run it. How does that compare to the records already in there?

Comment: I've already done that, and the records all match....I did run it against a new table though, I'll try running it against the same table.

Comment: When I run the inserts into __MigrationHistory provided by the UD -Script command, every single one fails with a Foreign Key constraint failure

Comment: That's good. Maybe something corrupted at the database level? You could try scripting out the table and data on the SQL side from another developer's working database and applying it to yours.

Comment: Working with Bob Archer on twitter we figured out this was the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29777200/403404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that Package Manager Console wasn't looking at my config file, so a quick search and I found that you have to not only set the Default Project in PMC (which I was doing), but the solution has to have the same project selected as Startup Project. ([Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777200/403404))